# HTML Button And Table Action

Tags: java, html, database, postgresql, netbeans

I am getting this error on my xhtml page

[Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtuqV.png)

IDE: Netbeans IDE 13

Server: GlassFish 6.2.5(6.2.1)

Here is my internetprog.xhtml code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/JSP_Servlet/XHtml.xhtml to edit this template
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.min.cc"/>
        <title>İnternet Programcılığı</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="lesson">
                <h1 id="dersler"> <a href="../index.xhtml">Dersler</a></h1>
                <ol>
                    <li> <a href="internetprog.xhtml">İnternet Programcılığı</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="siber.xhtml">Siber Güvenlik</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="programlama.xhtml">Programlama Dilleri</a></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <form>
                    <table border="3" width="100" cellpadding="5" id="ipveri">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>NOT LİNK</th>
                                <th>AÇIKLAMA</th>
                                <th>TARİH</th>   
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <ui:repeat value="#{InternetBean.list}" var="e">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>#{e.id}</td>
                                    <td>#{e.ilink}</td>
                                    <td>#{e.idescription}</td>
                                    <td>#{e.createdate}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
                <div>
                    <form>

                        <label>Not Link</label>
                        <input type="text" action="#{InternetBean.entity.ilink}"/>
                        <label>Açıklama</label>
                        <input type="text" action="#{InternetBean.entity.idescription}"/>

                        <button type="button"  action="#{InternetBean.create}">Create</button>
                        <button type="button"  action="#{InternetBean.update}">Update</button>
                        <button type="button"  action="#{InternetBean.update}">Delete</button>
                        
                        <!--ÇALIŞMIYOR-->
                        <!-- comment <h:commandButton   action="#{InternetBean.create}" value="Create"/>
                        <h:commandButton  rendered="#{InternetBean.entity.id!=null}" action="#{InternetBean.create}" value="Update"/>
                        <h:commandButton  rendered="#{InternetBean.entity.id!=null}" action="#{InternetBean.create}" value="Delete"/>-->

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is my university project. I need to add some item to my PostgreSQL DB when I click create.

I write #{InternetBean.create} command in button and #{e.id} on line 130 but they are not working correctly. Please help me about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

usually is used 'action="#{internetBean.create}'

the class name to use is in the tag "@Named" if you use only the tag(without 'value=InternetBean') then the action is lower case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).